# asus p7p55d-e pro won't post

Tags: intel-core-i5

Hello i'm trying to setup asus p7p55d-e pro with an intel i5-760 cpu.

- All required psu cables plugged in
- Video Only installed
- 1 DIMM in place

I get a CPU fan error and the CPU fan won't start => cpu temp over the limit

Tried google, and got not much but seems like no BIOS flash is required to support i5-760.

Any help appreciated. Guess it's time to stop custom builds.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the stock cooler that comes with the CPU or a 3rd party one?

Are you sure the fan is properly attached (all 4 pins used) to the proper fan header (should be labelled CPU_FAN, right near the CMOS battery)?

Have you tried the cooler/fan on another motherboard?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the stock cooler and a new one (artic cooler). None of them works. The only difference is that the artic-cooler starts to spin and then stops.

Comment: Sounds like a broken motherboard then, or a REALLY lame power supply. :)

Comment: damn! what a cluster-f* !